# odbc_pconnect works but PDO gives error

Tags: php, pdo, sybase, freetds, unixodbc

I set up a connection to a Sybase DB through unixODBC and FreeTDS on a CentOS server. (I don't own the Sybase server and I just have an account with read only permissions)

**TL;DR:** I can connect both with `odbc_pconnect` and PDO but when I execute the same query `odbc_pconnect` works while PDO returns an error

Full story: I created a simple test using `odbc_pconnect`

```
$query = "select COUNT(*) from table_name";

$conn = odbc_pconnect("myDSN", 'myusername', 'mypassword');

if(!$conn) 
    die("Connection failed");
if($result = odbc_exec($conn, $query)) 
{
    odbc_result_all($result);
}
```

The above code works and I obtain the count I want.

Then I tried using PDO

```
$connectionstring = "odbc:myDSN;";
try {
    $db = new \PDO(
    $connectionstring , 'myusername', 'mypassword');
} catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$rs = $db->query($query);
debug($db->errorInfo());
```

The connection is estabilished (no "connection failed" error) but then the server returns an error:

> [FreeTDS][SQL Server]ASA Error -121: Permission denied: 
>   you do not have permission to use the "CREATE PROCEDURE" statement 
>   (SQLExecute[262] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.4.16/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)

well, as you can see my query does not attempt to create any procedure

I tried different connection strings but the result does not change

I guess the problem is in my odbc and freeTDS configuration, rather than in PHP. But still the question remains: why different behaviors?

**edit** I found the same issue trying to access the datasource from the consolle: if I try with `tsql`

```
tsql -S myDSN -U myusername -P mypassword
```

I can execute the query. But when I access using `isql`:

```
isql -v myDSN myusername mypassword
```

I get the same error as aobove:

> [42501][FreeTDS][SQL Server]ASA Error -121: Permission denied: you do not have permission to use the "CREATE PROCEDURE" statement
>   [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute

I guess it is related to [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35570.1550/html/clcprgde/clcprgde194.htm)

PS
I'm using cakephp 3.1.11

Comment: No. I have no idea where it comes from

Comment: could be related to [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35570.1550/html/clcprgde/clcprgde194.htm)?

Comment: May you share this `$query` value?

Comment: It's in the question: it's a simple select query: `$query = "select COUNT(*) from table_name";`

Comment: Have u checked phpinfo, do you have installed/configured pdo odbc drivers?

Comment: `if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME'))
    echo 'PDO driver unavailable';` to check if you pdo driver installed and let me know

Comment: my phpinfo lists the following PDO drivers: mysql, odbc, sqlite. PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME is defined

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ PDO is installed by default since php 5.0 or 5.1

Comment: are you using the ORM of CakePHP?

Comment: @ElzoValugi, I've tried using cake ORM but it make use of PDO prepared statement so I get the same error

Comment: You have to ask for more privileges

Answer (score 0):

You may not create procedures, but CakePHP may do so in the background for you. If you only have read privileges you cannot create procedures, [source](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/BABCJGGB.htm):

> The following describes permission checks for create procedure (also when creating an extended procedure) that differ based on your granular permissions settings.:
>
> Granular permissions enabled - you must have the create procedure privilege. You must have the create any procedure privilege to run create procedure for other users.
>
> Granular permissions disabled - you must be the database owner or have the create procedure privilege.

Comment: thanks for your answer. As you can see from my code I don't use cakePHP but I use PDO directly. Of course if I use cake's ORM (and this is what I would like to do, in the end) I get the same error as cake internally uses PDO

Comment: also you linked a page from the MySQL documentation but I want to connect to a SyBase server trough  unixODBC and FreeTDS

Comment: you are right, but it is similar, I will update the answer

Comment: As I told you I'm not using cake ORM so it's not cake creating procedure:  it must be PDO or the odbc driver. I know that I need to have the privileges to create a procedure, but the question is: why are procedures beeing created when I just want to execute a simple SELECT query?

Comment: This is where you program fails: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c#L256. (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND or SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO). I am not sure where is the error on your code without a complete trace.  rc is the product of SQLExecute(S->stmt); (line 173) which means that your statement or your query can be wrong.